# Counting integers with hasNextInt

Tags: java, integer, java.util.scanner

I don't know what is wrong here

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CountingInts {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

          Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
          int count = 0;
          System.out.print("Numbers: ");

          while (input.hasNextInt()) {
              int x = input.nextInt();
              count = count + 1;
          }

          System.out.print(count);

          input.close();
    }       
}
```

I want to input a few integers i.g. (1 2 3 4 10) with spaces between then count how many numbers there are. So if the input is '1 2 3 4 10' the output is '5' since there are five numbers. I thought the while loop would do the trick but it seems to loop for ever. The problem is that it never does System.out.print(count); at the bottom :/ Anyone that knows whats wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the program<sup>1</sup>.  The problem is in the way that you are using it.  I assume that you are simply running it like this:

```
    java CountingInts
```

To make it stop, you can either give it something that is not a number (anything!) or you can tell the console driver that the inputs stream is at the notional "end of file"

---

The way to signal EOF on a console depends on the platform:

- On a Linux, Unix and Mac OSX console, the CTRL-D character means EOF.
- On a Windows console, the CTRL-Z character means EOF.
- In Eclipse console view, EOF is bound to CTRL-D or CTRL-Z, depending on your base platform.
- Other IDEs are probably the same as Eclipse.

(These character bindings may be changed.  Certainly they can be changed in the Linux, Unix and Eclipse cases.)

---

<sup>1 - That is an over-statement: there are a couple of minor problems. I'm also assuming that the *requirements* say that the program should stop counting when it sees something that isn't a number.</sup>

Comment: That's not the problem, I run it in Eclipse on Windows. The problem is that it never does System.out.print(count); at the bottom.

Comment: It does for me. For example, I enter "1, 2, 3, x" and it prints "3"

Comment: @Potato the reason why it does that is because it is stuck in an infinite loop thinking there is another integer coming when there is not. If you use breakpoints in debugging and walk through it you will see it is just waiting.

Comment: @Potato - if you enter "stop" it will output the count.  Try it!  Then figure out why ....

Comment: @electrometro I figured that out, I'm wondering how I can fix that infinite loop. I need to figure out what to change so it doesn't get stuck in the loop.

Comment: @Potato - precisely.  My answer tells you how to stop the infinite loop.  My previous comment repeats it.  It does not involve a code change.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CountingInts {

public static void main(String args[]) {

      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      int count = 0;
      System.out.print("Numbers: ");

      while (input.hasNextInt()) {

          // this line was your problem.
          //int x = input.nextInt(); 

          // Rewrite this as count++;
          //count = count + 1;
      }
      System.out.print(count);
      input.close();
      }       
}
```

Instead, try writing it like this.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CountingInts {

public static void main(String args[]) {

      int count = 0;

      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Numbers: ");

      while (input.hasNextInt()) {
          input.nextInt(); 
          count++;
      }
      System.out.print(count);
      input.close();
      }       
}
```

Whenever you refer to 'nextInt();', it's going to clear your buffer of that integer. You should leave the while loop as the input.hasNextInt(). This checks every input into the Scanner's buffer and makes sure that it is of type integer, then change the inside of the while loop to my suggested code. The input.nextInt() will clear the buffer and the count++ will increment the count variable by 1 each loop.

You might want to make this code more robust so that it will only allow input of type 'Integer'.

**Edit:** Hope this helped!

Comment: This is complete nonsense.  It makes no difference whether or not you assign the integer to a temporary variable or just throw it away.  The application will behave the same in either case.  Similarly, the change from `count = count + 1` to `count++` makes no difference.  They are equivalent.

Comment: First off, I used this code and it worked perfectly. Secondly, I'm not convinced that starting a reply with "this is complete nonsense" is the best way to make a point. He simply requested help on his program and I gave him a viable and effective solution for his program. Thanks though!

Comment: Finally, the program already "only allows integers", and stops when it sees something that isn't an integer.  Sure, you could change it to skip over non-integers, or print an error message ... but we don't know what the requirements are.  It is plausible that the requirements are to be have *exactly* as the program has been written.  It is bad advice to suggest functional "improvements" like this if you don't know what the requirements are.

Comment: **"// this line was your problem."** - Complete nonsense!  There is NO problem there.  His original program works just fine.  If you are going to suggest minor stylistic improvements, then make it clear that that is what you are doing.  The way you wrote it clearly implies that theses are fixes for his problem.  In fact his real problem is that he didn't know how to tell his program to stop counting ... e.g. with an EOF.

Comment: You're incredibly rude. I'm submitting an answer to help another programmer, I'm not asking to be critiqued or bashed by you. Once again, thanks. He's not reading a file, why would you check for the end of one? The question asks about inputting integers and counting how many were put into a scanner, not how to read a file.

Comment: That is not rude.  It is simply blunt.  Rude is when someone makes the comments personal.  If you are not prepared to be critiqued for posting misleading answers, don't post them.

Comment: Guys, I'm really thankful that you helped me. You both did your best and I'm thankful for that, please don't hate on each other, your both trying to help a beginner programmer out.

Comment: When you're saying that every suggestion I'm making is "nonsense", I take it offensively. @Stephen C

Comment: The question was about how to fix the problem; i.e. how to stop the infinite loop.  But the problem was not in the program.

Comment: @Coleton - *"When you're saying that every suggestion I'm making is "nonsense", I take it offensively."* - Well you need to learn not to.  You are too thin-skinned for this site.  I am not going to moderate my language just for you, and you will find that there are a few others here who won't either.

Comment: @Stephen C - How does that one saying go? If you can't say something nice, don't say anything at all. :)

Comment: @Coleton and there are a couple more:  "Let's call a spade a spade" and "If you can't stand the heat, stay out of the kitchen.".  Note I never once called you an idiot for posting nonsense.  Really smart people do it too ... sometimes.  But nonsense is nonsense.  And I note that you still haven't corrected your Answer.